# Create sublists knowing the lengths of each list

Tags: python, list, tuples, sublist

I'm having some trouble trying to create this.

I have the following lists:

```
values = [(3, 50), (4, 20), (10, 30), (11, 60), (12, 70), (13, 20)]
lens = [2,4]
```

What I want to do is to generate another list of sublists knowing the exact length of each sublist, so the output would be this one:

```
result = [[(3, 50), (4, 20)], [(10, 30), (11, 60), (12, 70), (13, 20)]]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you attempt to write code for it? Given the `2`, can you create the first sublist? Given the `4`, can you create the next (hint: where should it start?) Given a sequence of such numbers, can you create all of them (hint: think of a way to track where the next one should start)? Given the ability to create each of them in sequence, can you make the final list?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an iterator out of `values` and call `next` on it in a list comprehension:

```
iterator = iter(values)
result = [[next(iterator) for _ in range(length)] for length in lens]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible approaches.

A more 'basic' one, managing indices 'by hand':

```
values = [(3, 50), (4, 20), (10, 30), (11, 60), (12, 70), (13, 20)]
lens = [2,4]

def slices1(values, lens):
    out = []
    index = 0
    for length in lens:
        out.append(values[index:index+length])
        index += length
    return out

print(slices1(values, lens))
# [[(3, 50), (4, 20)], [(10, 30), (11, 60), (12, 70), (13, 20)]]
```

Another one, using an iterator on the list, and [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get successive slices from it:

```
from itertools import islice

def slices2(values, lens):
    it = iter(values)
    out = [list(islice(it,length)) for length in lens]
    return out

print(slices2(values, lens))
# [[(3, 50), (4, 20)], [(10, 30), (11, 60), (12, 70), (13, 20)]]
```